# Find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume $U$ is uniform on $(0, 2\pi)$ and $Z$, independent of $U$, is exponential with rate $\lambda=1$.  Now assume $X$ and $Y$ are defined by: $X = \sqrt{2Z} \cos(U)$ and $Y = \sqrt{2Z}\sin(U)$.  Find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

I am stuck on this question while reviewing for my test next week.

I assume that I need to manipulate $X$ and $Y$ in terms of $U$ and $Z$, since I am given the fact that $U$ and $Z$ are independent, and therefore $f(U,Z) = f(U)f(Z)$.  However the question asks about $f(X,Y)$.  I'm pretty sure that I can't just substitute the distributions of $U$ and $Z$ in the equations of $X$ and $Y$, but I'm not sure how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

One possible approach consists in applying the change of variables method. To begin with, notice that

\begin{cases}
U = \displaystyle\arctan\left(\frac{Y}{X}\right)\\\\
Z = \displaystyle\frac{X^{2} +  Y^{2}}{2}
\end{cases}

Therefore we have

\begin{align*}
f_{X,Y}(x,y) & = f_{U,Z}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right),\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2}\right)|\det J(x,y)|\\
& = f_{U}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)f_{Z}\left(\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2}\right)|\det J(x,y)|
\end{align*}

since $U$ and $Z$ are independent. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: ok, so once I found the determinant (which should be -1 if I did my math correctly), I can then substitute the distribution of U and Z into the joint distribution.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but for the distribution of U, for example, will it be $\frac{1}{2}arctan\frac{y}{x}$?

Comment: The uniform distribution on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ is given by $f_{U}(u) = 1/2\pi$. Thus, when you plug in the argument $\arctan$, it keeps to be the same constant.

Comment: i think i get it now.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :)